# How can i return list of class in doInBackground AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I'm try return to user list of class in do in background of async task,my class this:

```
public class ReadingModel{
    @SerializedName("BillID")
    @Expose
    private String BillID;
    @SerializedName("Mablagh")
    @Expose
    private String Mablagh;
    @SerializedName("PayID")
    @Expose
    private String PayID;
    public String getBillID(){return BillID;}
    public void setBillID(String BillID){this.BillID=BillID;}
    public String getMablagh(){return Mablagh;}
    public void setMablagh(String Mablagh){this.Mablagh=Mablagh;}
    public String getPayID(){return PayID;}
    public void setPayID(String PayID){this.PayID=PayID;}
    public static class List extends ArrayList<MobilePostModel> {}
}
```

and call my async task with this way:

```
List<ReadingModel> List_result= new AsyncRead().execute(params).get();
```

and this is my async task code:

```
private class AsyncRead extends AsyncTask<GetReadingTask,Void,String>{
        ReadingModel.List x;
        @Override
        protected List<ReadingModel> doInBackground(GetReadingTask... getReadingTasks) {
            ir.behineh.wepapiinterface.GETREADINGINTERFACE.GetReading taskService=ServiceGenerator.createService(ir.behineh.wepapiinterface.GETREADINGINTERFACE.GetReading.class);
            Call<ReadingModel.List> tasks=taskService.getReadings("application/x-www-form-urlencoded","application/json","bearer ");
            try {
                x=tasks.execute().body();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
```

but in this line:

```
 protected List<ReadingModel> doInBackground(GetReadingTask... getReadingTasks) {
```

get this error:

> attemption to use incompatible return type

How can solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last generic type is the return type. You have `String`, but returning `List<ReadingModel>`. You need to change your class declaration:

```
private class AsyncRead extends AsyncTask<GetReadingTask, Void, List<ReadingModel>> {
    //...
}
```